# Missing or insufficient permissions firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2, firebase-security

I'm getting error: Firebase missing or insufficient permissions

Code :
  const demoCollectionRef = this.db.collection('items');
  return demoCollectionRef.add(item);

I think this error is because of .add method of angularfire2.

Firestore Rules:

```
function isAuthenticated() {
  return request.auth.uid != null;
}

function isAdmin() {
    return request.auth.token.admin == true;
}

allow create: if isAuthenticated();
allow update, delete: if isAdmin(); // .add method checks update rules 
// at the place of checking the create rules, which make it send error.
```

But if I change the update rule to:
allow update, delete: if isAuthenticated(); it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout this url for firebase data authentication

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Comment: I'm doing as it is described on it.

Comment: @Aman did you find the solution? I am facing similar issue and I have created this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345129/missing-or-insufficient-permissions-during-post-a-document-to-firestore-using-cu