# Missing or insufficient permissions during post a document to Firestore using Custom Token

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Final Goal: my company will start use Firestore to update transaction status to our Mobile Application and Angular 9 frontend.

Immediate challenge: learn how use Custom Token.

Current issue: I get this erro although it is owner:

```
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
```

I can't understand why getting PERMISSION_DENIED if the idToken is related to the Collection Owner.

IAM Admin showing the user is owner:

[image: iam admin]

[image: settings iam]

Steps to reproduce:

1 - I succesfully can get a Custom Token from this code published to https://us-central1-firetestjimis.cloudfunctions.net/getCustomToken

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

export const getCustomToken = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    if (admin.apps.length < 1) {   //Checks if app already initialized
        admin.initializeApp();
    }
    const uid = "User UID copied from https://console.firebase.google.com/project/firetestjimis/authentication/users"; 

    admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
        .then(function (customToken) {
            console.log(customToken.toString);
            response.send(customToken);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
        });
});
```

2 - I can successfully post this Custom Token to https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken and get back idTken like

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyCustomTokenResponse",
  "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiI ... .... aMorw",
  "refreshToken": "AE0u-Ney9OJ04Z3xA7ACsmI1S637hXeuCTEdaEU9cxhhPnlwh-9q0X7QpSxVRIYdTdrTgXUbS9Q6yUdAWVeXzhGMiLLLHtwSWSoVSWnZs3Gp1Sb050tThNPQiSsSss8GkCigft3PTBkY4nIbRy3A5dA8FHCLbMYQSfKYqvu8To76UyMVCYONJOM",
  "expiresIn": "3600",
  "isNewUser": false
}
```

8 - Now I want to post a simple document to Firestore collection throw

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/firetestjimis/databases/(default)/documents/transfer' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGc ... ... iNaMorw' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "fields": {
    "id": {
      "stringValue": "1"
    },      
    "status": {
      "stringValue": "fracasso"
    }
  }
}'
```

and I get the error mentioned above.

IN case it is relevant, here is the collection manually created:

[image: collection manually created]

*** edit

Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if false;
      allow update, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Desire:

Anyone can read but only post with valid idToken resulted from custom token can create and update.

Comment: It seems like you're confusing project-level permissions (IAM) with Firebase Auth. Firebase Auth ID Tokens are used in conjunction with Firestore security rules, not IAM permissions. Can you provide your rules and what you're expecting to happen?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh, thanks. I will add above the ruels and desired behaviour. Meanwhile, kindly, can you explain what is the difference between (1) Firebase Auth ID Tokens are used in conjunction with Firestore security rules and (2) IAM permissions ? In my case I believe I have to rely on (1) Firebase Auth ID Tokens are used in conjunction with Firestore security rules, right?

Comment: IAM permissions are in play when you are accessing APIs with a Google OAuth access token. When authorizing with an access token, rules are not evaluated. Firebase Auth ID tokens are meant to be used by client applications to safely and directly access data in a controlled manner mediated by rules.